# Trying to sort a list of elements

Tags: bash, macos, sorting, unix

I want to sort the list by percentages but I can't do it. The command I'm using to do it is:

`for alpha0 in $(seq 4 0.1 6) ; do echo -n "$alpha0: "; scripts/run_vad.sh $alpha0 | grep TOTAL; done | sort -t ':' -k 2 -n`

What is displayed in the terminal of a MacBook M1 Pro is: '

```
4.1: ===> TOTAL: 89.120%
4.2: ===> TOTAL: 89.123%
4.3: ===> TOTAL: 89.151%
4.4: ===> TOTAL: 89.201%
4.5: ===> TOTAL: 89.222%
4.6: ===> TOTAL: 89.243%
4.7: ===> TOTAL: 89.265%
4.8: ===> TOTAL: 89.278%
4.9: ===> TOTAL: 89.291%
4: ===> TOTAL: 89.069%
5.1: ===> TOTAL: 89.305%
5.2: ===> TOTAL: 89.285%
5.3: ===> TOTAL: 89.276%
5.4: ===> TOTAL: 89.262%
5.5: ===> TOTAL: 89.246%
5.6: ===> TOTAL: 89.227%
5.7: ===> TOTAL: 89.175%
5.8: ===> TOTAL: 89.151%
5.9: ===> TOTAL: 89.136%
5: ===> TOTAL: 89.292%
6: ===> TOTAL: 89.100%'.
```

I don't understand why it's not working.

I was trying to sort the last column, the numbers with percentages, and I'm thinking that maybe the problem is that the numbers 4, 5, and 6 don't have the decimal .0 but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: gnu coreutils sort on Linux works for me with `sort -k 4 -n`

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

If you use `:` as the delimiter, `-k2` starts from the second column, i.e. it sorts

```
===> TOTAL: 89.120%
```

Start with the third column instead, i.e. `-k3`.

Comment: As long as there's an `n` somewhere you won't see a difference, I just didn't realize it was assumed to be elsewhere on the command line. I'll remove my original comment now and this one soon.